# SQL Update Query with from clause Optimization

Tags: sql-server, winforms, sql-update, query-optimization, database-deadlocks

I have two tables which are heavily queried by multiple users. Average 100+ (update/select) queries/second requests are made for these tables.

Parent
Child

*GrantParent is not involved in join so, I said only two tables

I need to reorder all children for each parent. There can be 3000-4000 parents and each parent may have around same number of children.

Column Types:
ParentID GUID 
ChildIndex int
FileID Varchar
IsDeleted bit

Tables have clustered index on PK and non-clustered index on columns being used in where.

```
UPDATE C SET C.ChildIndex = T.ReOrderedChildIndex FROM [Child] C INNER JOIN
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dbo.Child.[ParentID] ORDER BY [ChildIndex] asc) AS ReOrderedChildIndex,
        dbo.Child.ChildIndex,
        dbo.Child.FileID, 
        dbo.Child.ParentID

FROM    dbo.Child  WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Parent  WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.Child.ParentID = dbo.Parent.ParentID
WHERE   (dbo.Parent.GrandParentID = 1) AND (dbo.Child.IsDeleted = 0) 
) T 
ON C.FileID =T.FileID AND (C.ParentID=T.ParentID) AND (C.IsDeleted = 0)
```

It looks above query take longer time and put select queries on wait even I have used WITH (NOLOCK) in all data selection stored procedures.

There is another query which reorder parents in same way as done for childs in above query.

In Activity Monitor the locks are shown for select stored procedures.

What is the best way to reorder perform reordering?

I am having following issues and believe they are stems from these queries:
1- Randomly deadlock occur.
2- Often connection pool time out occurs.

*Database is accessed by a windows application using Entlib 4.0 with connection pooling enabled, pool max size 200.

SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Nolock will not work in a data changing query, insert, update, delete, or merge.

Comment: Do you only allow one level for the parent-child relationship?  Parent->Child or Parent->Child1->Child2->Child3?

Comment: There is only one level. Child can only be child and parent can only be parent so, no recursion or self join involves. All parents are unique for one grandparent and all child are unique for each parent.  Regarding Nolock in update.. I thought update have a nested select so nolock should be considered for select?

Comment: You may be able to NOLOCK parent but you definitely cannot tell it not to hold locks on the table(s) being updated.

Comment: DO NOT use NOLOCK when updating your data. You can corrupt your database. You need to get out of the habit of just throwing NOLOCK on your queries when they aren't fast enough. That is NOT magic go fast button. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: @Sean Lange, thanks for info I removed NOLOCK FROM nested select

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend restructuring your data to a more flexible schema.  This schema will allow multiple levels so you can merge GrandParent, Parent, and Child into one logical relationship table and one logical details table.  You'll also be able to take advantage of indexes to reduce locks and improve performance.

You'll have to re-build your hierarchy after any relationship changes.  The way I wrote the script below should minimize this impact on your system.  You will no longer be updating the entire table, just the pieces that have changed.

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.EntityName
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    ParentID INT -- Todo: Add foreign key back to dbo.EntityName
    -- Todo: Add primary key
);
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Hierarchy
(
    ParentID INT,  -- Todo: Add foreign key back to dbo.EntityName
    ChildID INT, -- Todo: Add foreign key back to dbo.EntityName
    ChildLevel INT
);
GO
```

**Populate script (slightly rough around the edges):**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspBuildHierarchy]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #Hierarchy
    (
        ParentID INT,
        ChildID INT,
        ChildLevel INT
    );

    -- Add the root of your hierarchy
    INSERT INTO #Hierarchy VALUES (1, 1, 0); 

    DECLARE @ChildLevel INT = 1,
            @LastCount INT = 1;

    WHILE (@LastCount > 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #Hierarchy
        SELECT
            E.ParentID,
            E.ID,
            @ChildLevel + 1
        FROM dbo.EntityName E
        INNER JOIN #Hierarchy H ON H.ChildID = E.ParentID
            AND H.ChildLevel = (@ChildLevel - 1)
        LEFT JOIN #Hierarchy EH ON EH.ParentID = E.ParentID
            AND EH.ChildID = E.ID
        WHERE EH.ChildLevel IS NULL;

        SET @LastCount = @@ROWCOUNT;
        SET @ChildLevel = @ChildLevel + 1;
    END

    MERGE INTO dbo.Hierarchy OH
    USING
    (
        SELECT
            ParentID,
            ChildID,
            ChildLevel
        FROM #Hierarchy
    ) NH
    ON OH.ParentID = NH.ParentID
        AND OH.ChildID = NH.ChildID
    WHEN MATCHED AND OH.ChildLevel <> NH.ChildLevel THEN
        UPDATE
            SET ChildLevel = NH.ChildLevel
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT
        VALUES
        (
            NH.ParentID,
            NH.ChildID,
            NH.ChildLevel
        )
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
        THEN DELETE;
END
GO
```

**Query for all of an entity's children:**

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.EntityName E
INNER JOIN dbo.Hierarchy H ON H.ChildID = E.ID
    AND H.ParentID = @EntityNameID;
```

Comment: At the moment I have 3 tables after Normalization. GrandParent, Parent, Child. Each entity have many related attributes so they are kept separately into relevant tables. How would it fit into your proposed schema?

Comment: You've only told us how they are related at this point, I'd have to know what the tables store.

Comment: to further clarify, each table have around 6 more columns which are not involved in these reorder/updates hence, a normalized form was preferred over having one table for parent and chillds. also there only one level. one parent cannot be child to others and one child can have only one parent so, as per my knowledge having two tables was better.  Is it bad?

Comment: Its not necessarily bad, its just fixed and requires some duplication.  What are you doing with the ChildIndex?  How often are you using ChildIndex?